# How do I use a javascript injection to click on links of a specific class?

Tags: javascript, code-injection

I have a page with many links that execute certain actions on click. Example:

```
<a class="x" onclick="somefunction(does_something)" href="javascript:void(0)">x</a>
```

I want to use a javascript injection to click all of them on the page. So far, I tried:

```
javascript:document.getElementsByClassName("x")[0].click();
```

But that doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you are getting the element you want? Make sure your code is run after the document renders? Make sure there are no errors in your JavaScript console.  Not enough information to help you.

Comment: Well, it works when I click on the links manually. So, I assume that means the page is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd suggest using jQuery, it's a lot easier to understand. Next, you can't really 'click' links dynamically and run it's function. You need to simply run a function on all the links and use it's address.

```
window.open( $('.x').attr( 'href' ), '_blank' );
```

Iterating through all links and opening them inside a container...

#### jQuery

```
$('#some_link_container').find('a').each(function() {
    var link = $(this); // This is the current link in the iteration
    window.open( link.attr( 'href' ), '_blank' ); // Prepare for mass computer lag
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="some_link_container">
    <a href="http://google.com/" class="x">A link</a>
    <a href="http://google.com/" class="x">A link</a>
    <a href="http://google.com/" class="x">A link</a>
    <a href="http://google.com/" class="x">A link</a>
</div>
```

**If you are trying to run a function onclick**, it's best to use a event listener rather then onclick. Something like the following

### [Event Listener Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8mRxJ/)

Here we listen to a click on any link inside our container, then we run a function.

```
$('#some_link_container').find('a').each(function() { // Each link inside our div container
    var link = $(this); // The current link
    link.on('click', function(e) { // When the link is clicked
        e.preventDefault(); // Stop the link from forwarding to that page
        goodbye( link.attr('href') ); // Run our function onclick 
    });
});

var goodbye = function(link) {
        alert( 'Goodbye guest! Forwarding you to: ' + link );
        window.open( link, '_self' );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your JS is inline, you can simply call what you need right in the href...

```
<a href="javascript:functionName('parameter1','parameter1','parameter1')">
Click to execute JS</a>
```

...but not wise if the parameters aren't predefined by you.  Definitely don't do this if your parameters take user input and update/execute against your database, but it does work.

Comment: Rereading the question, I now see you are asking something different than what I first interpreted the question to be.

Comment: All of the functions take "this" as an argument, so I don't know if it'll work by simply calling the function.

Comment: We've pretty much given you your only options. Using the direct method of calling functions as I showed above is the best way. You can then delegate based on the 'class' of the link, or w/e to define what function is called like `if ( link.attr('class') === 'x' ) { goodbye( link.attr('href') ) // do something }`